# whats wrong with my code(copying string using pointers?)?

Tags: c, pointers

```
//a function that copies one string to another
copy(char *,char*);
main()
{
    char one[20],two[20];
    printf("enter two sentences \n\n");
    gets(one);//first string
    gets(two);//second string
    copy(one,two);
    printf("%s",two);
}
copy(char *s1,char *s2)
{
    while(*s1!='\0')
    {
        s2=s1;
        s1++;
        s2++;
    }
    s2='\0';
}
```

what wrong with the above program ? why  the string 'one' is not getting copied to string 'two'?please explain with  the help of pointer

Comment: Think over why you are using the `*`-operator here: `*s1!='\0'` and do not use it here: `s1=s2;` and here `s2='\0';`.

Answer (score 2):

It's because this:

```
s2 = s1;
```

changes the *pointer* `s2` so that it points to the content of `s1`.

What you want to do is copy the *content:*

```
*s2 = *s1;
```

A decent compiler should also have given you a warning on this line:

```
s2 = '\0';
```

since you're assigning a `char` to a `char *`. It should be:

```
*s2 = '\0';
```

Enacting those changes, the function would then be (including using some, IMNSHO, better variable names):

```
void copy (char *from, char *to) {
    while (*from != '\0') {
        *to = *from;
        from++;
        to++;
    }
    *to = '\0';
}
```

---

Or, once your brain has been warped by several decades of C use like mine :-)

```
void copy (char *from, char *to) {
    while (*to++ = *from++);
}
```

Comment: Why use the `do...while` loop? Isn't the `while` loop better?

Comment: @CoolGuy, the advantage of the `do.while` is that it checks the terminating condition _after_ the iteration, meaning you don't need more code at the end to copy or put a string terminator.

Comment: I know that. But isn't a `while` loop better in this case(as there are less characters to type)? Also, I didn't mean the `while` loop in the answer... I meant using `while (*to++ = *from++);` instead of `do {} while (*to++ = *from++);`.

Comment: @CoolGuy, yes, I see what you're getting at now, I'll incorporate the shorter version.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> /* for strchr */

void copy(const char *, char*); /* use void to return nothing */

int main(void) /* main() is not valid */
{
    char one[20], two[20];
    char *ptr;

    printf("enter two sentences \n\n");
    /* gets is deprecated, use fgets in order to avoid overflows */
    fgets(one, sizeof one, stdin);
    /* fgets leaves a trailing newline, remove it */
    if ((ptr = strchr(one, '\n'))) *ptr = '\0';
    fgets(two, sizeof two, stdin); /* why? is gonna be replaced by one */
    copy(one, two);
    printf("%s\n", two);
    return 0;
}

void copy(const char *s1, char *s2) /* s1 is not modified, use const */
{
    while(*s1 != '\0')
    {
        *s2 = *s1; /* Don't assign addresses, assign values */
        s1++;
        s2++;
    }
    *s2 = '\0';
}
```